# Plotting a 3D line and a 3D surface in matplotlib: why does the line appear on top?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

Hi I am trying to plot a 3D surface plot and a 3D line in the same plot. The line represents gradient descent down the surface. The plot looks like this:

[image: 3D gaussian surface plot and 3D line showing gradient descent]

I notice that the line plot appears to be layered above the surface plot, even though the surface should partially hide the line at this angle.

This is the code that handles plotting:

```
# Make figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize =(8,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d')
# Plot the surface function we are minimising
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues_r')) 
# Plot the line
ax.plot(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

x,y,z are the coords of the line and X,Y,Z are the coords of the surface, calculated in a different section of the code.

Is there a way to make the surface and the line overlap each other depending on which is closest to the viewer from any given angle?

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't implement full 3D functionality. Matplotlib's faq suggests using mayavi if you need such.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with the way matplotlib renders 3d graphs. The library was designed primarily to deal with 2D visualizations, which is reflected in [the  way 3D visualizations are rendered](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection). 3D objects like the surface and line you render in your example are rendered according to the z-order of the objects. Basically, the 3d objects is rendered as a whole, and partly overlapping objects will not be rendered correctly. Theoretically you should be able to circumvent this problem by chopping the objects (for instance the 3d line) into smaller portions like so:

```py
# amount of samples the line has
n_samples = 100
# normal plotting of 3d line
ax.plot(x,y,z)

# splitted plotting
step = 1
for i in range(step, n_samples, step)
  ax.plot(x[i-1:i+step],y[i-1:i+step],z[i-1:step])
```

Where step determines the size of segments you will render. However I have not managed to get this working with an approximation of your data which I replicated in my own system. There is also a `zsort` parameter for [Poly3DCollections](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.set_sort_zpos) which can be changed to determine how the z-order is determined for the object.

Conclusion is that I can't really tell you how this issue can be fixed, however that it is a fundamental issue with how matplotlib displays 3D graphics. Knowing this might help you find a workaround although it might be a little 'hacky'. Goodluck!